# WPF - Binding plus a tweak

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, wcf-binding

I am wondering if there is a way with WPF binding to set the value via binding plus tweak it.

For example I have the width of a border being set to the canvas that contains it:

```
Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=mainCanvas, Mode=Default}"
```

Because I am doing a border with rounded corners.  the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left for the border are both set to -5.  This makes the border end 5 too soon (really 10 too soon with the rounded corners on the other side).

Is there a way to do something similar to this:

```
Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=mainCanvas, Mode=Default} + 5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a ValueConverter would work. See this video tutorial: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=26730

You may also look into using the Margin property.

Answer (score 3):

Either write your own `IValueConverter` that does that, and specify it in the binding, or use some of the existing generic ones that allow you to embed expressions directly into XAML - e.g. [PyBinding](http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=340).

Comment: PyBinding is unreleased code.  There is no download for it that I could find (though it looked really useful).